# Migration from angular 4 to angular 6 main-client.js and main-server.js is not updating

Tags: angular

While i am migrating from angular 4 to angular 6 and making changes in html then main-client.js and main-server.js is not updating. So changes are not reflecting in HTML.

```
Migrated package.json in angular 6 is given below.
```

Getting error in Cmd while running after migration Please find the error message in below image

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
 {
      "name": "AspNetCore2_Angular4_SPA_publish_demo",
      "private": true,
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "6.0.7",
        "@angular/common": "6.0.7",
        "@angular/compiler": "6.0.7",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.7",
        "@angular/core": "6.0.7",
        "@angular/forms": "6.0.7",
        "@angular/http": "6.0.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.7",
        "@angular/platform-server": "6.0.7",
        "@angular/router": "6.0.7",
        "@ngtools/webpack": "6.0.8",
        "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.6",
        "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
        "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
        "aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "5.2.0",
        "bootstrap": "4.1.1",
        "css": "2.2.3",
        "css-loader": "0.28.11",
        "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
        "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.12",
        "expose-loader": "0.7.5",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
        "file-loader": "1.1.11",
        "html-loader": "0.5.5",
        "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
        "jquery": "3.3.1",
        "json-loader": "0.5.7",
        "preboot": "6.0.0-beta.4",
        "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
        "rxjs": "6.2.1",
        "style-loader": "0.21.0",
        "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
        "typescript": "2.9.2",
        "url-loader": "1.0.1",
        "webpack": "4.14.0",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.22.2",**strong text**
        "webpack-merge": "4.1.3",
        "zone.js": "0.8.26"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/chai": "4.1.4",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
        "chai": "4.1.2",
        "jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
        "karma": "2.0.4",
        "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
        "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
        "karma-webpack": "3.0.0"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide your error message

Comment: HI ,I have provided the screenshot of error message on top.